# Which of the two JDBC query batching approaches is faster?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, batch-processing

I am trying to run update statements in multiple batches using rownum on a table which has millions of records.

The first approach is to batch all the queries together and then running `executeBatch()` method as below,

```
for (i = num; i < limit; i += num) {
    String query = "update Table set someColumn ='T' where rownum<=" + i;
    preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(query);
    preparedStatement.addBatch();
}
preparedStatement.executeBatch();
dbConnection.commit();
```

Second approach is to run one batch update statement and committing after every batch like as shown below,

```
String query = "update Table set someColumn ='T' where rownum<=?";
preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(query);
int count = 1;
while (count > 0) {
    preparedStatement.setInt(1, num);
    count = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    dbConnection.commit();
}
```

I thought second approach is cleaner since it commits after every batch, however the first approach is taking much lesser time than the second approach.

Can someone explain to me why this is so? Or if there's any mistake in my approaches and understanding.

Comment: [Quote from Tom Kyte](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4951966319022): "*Frequently commiting (...) slows you down, yes, that is right, SLOWS YOU DOWN -- makes you run SLOOOWWWWEEERRR*". Why don't you just update everything in a single statement? That is most likely going to be faster. And the first loop is wrong anyway. In the first iteration it updates 1 row, in the second iteration it updates 2 rows, then 3 row, then 4 rows and in the end all "limit" rows. That does not make any sense. You should **at least** add a `where somecolumn <> 'T'` to it as well

Comment: @above, I have to mention, in my production proof of concept query, there is a where condition, here for the sake of simplicity, I removed those conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can someone explain to me why this is so?

There are a number of different things that can be optimized here:

1. the work done by the JDBC/ODBC driver and db engine to prepare and
   parse the statement
2. the round-trip traffic between the client and db server
3. the work done by the db engine to open and close (i.e. commit
   or rollback) a transaction

You examples are optimizing different things:

- By using a bound parameter (as in your second example) you only
  prepare the statement once, which reduces the work done by the
  ODBC/JDBC driver and probably the database engine as well.
- By executing the batch less often (1st example), you are reducing the
  number of round trips between the client and the server.
- By committing less often (1st example again) you are reducing the number
  of times the database needs to open and close a transaction.

As you found, the bottleneck turns out to be the overhead with opening and closing transactions. The multiple round trips aren't helping either. Those are more costly than not using a bound parameter.

Happily, in this example you can optimize all three things. You can use a bound parameter, send all the commands to the database in one go, and execute a single commit. See the answer by Jean de Lavarene.

Do note the change in behavior though: if you commit in a single batch, one error will cause everything in the batch to roll back. This may be exactly what you want, but if not, such considerations may take precedence over performance.

Answer (score 3):

Use batching with different bind variables of the same prepared statement:

```
String query = "update Table set someColumn ='T' where rownum<=?";
preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(query);
for (i = num; i < limit; i += num) {
  preparedStatement.setInt(1, num);
  count = preparedStatement.addBatch();
}
preparedStatement.executeBatch();
dbConnection.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use one batch.

#### Logical reason:

Unless the high water mark of your commit size exceeds the log limit of your server (in which case your transaction will roll back when part way through), you probably want *all* the statements to complete successfully, or *all* to fail. It's much harder to unravel partial DB updates, and (depending on your situation) you may leave data in an inconsistent state if only some updates succeed.

#### Performance reason:

Allow the DB to optimize parsing one command, coordinate all activities, start only one transaction, and make only one commit.